# Get either the value or null entry on row in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have four tables, products, priceplans, and two category tables as follows:

```
products
---------
product_id
a
b

priceplans
---------
priceplan_id
a
b
product_id (can be null)
price

categoryA
---------
a (id)
category_name

categoryB
---------
b (id)
category_name
```

In the priceplans a and b are category ids in other tables, the combination `(a,b,product_id)` is unique but product_id can also be null, and the priceplan should then use the general priceplan for the `(a,b,null)` combination. That is the theory, but it is not working out as well as I had hoped and I havent managed to construct a query to only filter them out.

Example:

```
products - 3 products, 2 in the same category, one in another category
product_id a b
         1 1 1
         2 1 1
         3 1 2

priceplans - 3 plans, 
1 is for the default (a,b)=(1,1) category combination when there is no product_id, 
2 is supposed to override the default as we have declared a product_id, and 
3 is the default for (a,b)=(1,2) combination
priceplan_id a b product_id price
           1 1 1       null 10
           2 1 1          2 15
           3 1 2       null 12
```

What I want the outcome to look like when I join products with the priceplans is:

```
product_id a b priceplan_id price
         1 1 1            1    10
         2 1 1            2    15
         3 1 2            3    12
```

If for the product with a category combination (a,b)=(1,1) and id=1 i want the priceplan with combination (a,b,1) if it exists, if not i want the (a,b,null) priceplan. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your query so far?

Comment: right now it looks like:`select * from products
LEFT JOIN priceplans pp
  ON otherTable.id=pp.a
  AND otherTable2.id=pp.b
  AND(products.product_id=pp.product_id OR pp.product_id IS NULL)`
But it returns two rows for every product, one with the product_id and one with it as null, i only want the one with product_id if it exists, otherwise the null row

Comment: Are we missing a table definition?  Your example query has otherTable.  If products only has one record with product_id = 1, then you should never get the 2 results your showing.  Either the product is in priceplan or it's not.  You'd get the first row if it's in priceplan and the second row if it's not.  This leads me to believe that we need to know how otherTable is involved.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to create the query I was looking for:

```
select pro.*, pp.* from products pro
left join price_plans pp
  on pro.a=pp.a
  and pro.b=pp.b
  and (pro.product_id=pp.product_id or pp.product_id is null)
left join price_plans pp2
  on pro.a=pp2.a
  and pro.b=pp2.b
  and pp2.product_id =pro.product_id

where pp.product_id <=> pp2.product_id
```